# symptoms of not calling NetworkStream dispose

Tags: .net

Let me preface this question with I know this is not something that I should be doing, but still I am curious.

What kinds of errors should I expect to see if I close the `TcpClien`t socket but do not call `Dispose` on the corresponding `NetworkStream`?

Should I expect to see any errors when I re-open the `TcpClient` with the `NetworkStream` still not disposed?

Comment: Only ever dispose objects that you created.  You didn't create the NetworkStream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you close a `TcpClient`, it disposes the stream.